# Add and edit data to postgresql with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a ruby code that should integrate with database. I use this code:

```
user_id = params[:user_id].to_i

sql = "SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE user_id = #{user_id}"

user_stats = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

but adding rows to database like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_custom_fields (id, user_id, name, value, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (#{last_id}, #{user_id}, 'user_field_#{user_field_id[0]["id"]}', '#{personality}', '#{formatted}', '#{formatted}')"
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

won't increase the sequence table and I can't edit this table using this way.

How should I add data to these tables that the sequence tables increase automatically.

Comment: Please post the DDL of `user_custom_fields` table.

Comment: Any particular reason for not creating a  `UserCustomField` model and querying the db with it (e.g. `UserCustomField.create`)?